# Dependency injection in Laravel service layer class

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, service-layer

In my Laravel 6.9.0 app, I have some code which I need to run from many places, so I'm working on creating this as a service layer.

I've created the file `/app/Actions/Music/GetRecentArtists.php` and added it to my composer autoload config:

```
<?php

namespace App\Actions\Music;

use \Barryvanveen\Lastfm\Lastfm;

class GetRecentArtists {

    public function get(Lastfm $lastfm)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

But when I run it in Tinker using:

```
(new App\Actions\Music\GetRecentArtists())->get()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Too few arguments to function App/Actions/Music/GetRecentArtists::get(), 0 passed in Psy Shell code on line 1 and exactly 1 expected
```

I'd thought that dependency injection would inject the `Lastfm` instance. When I remove the function argument, it runs fine.

Comment: Not really related to dependency injection, but might be better to use a [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes) instead.

Comment: where is located  Barryvanveen\Lastfm\Lastfm class?
best approach load in composer file  and run dumpautoload command

Comment: Laravel dependency injection only works if you pull the `GetRecentArtists` from the service container. It does not work if you create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [`resolve`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/container#resolving) method, the Laravel service container should inject the dependency for you:

```
resolve('App\Actions\Music\GetRecentArtists')
```